# choosing a device to act as a server.

Tags: networking, unix

This is not a coding question. This is a question coming out of curiosity around my personal project.

I have a simple server side web-sever which can be connected to limited set of clients over network. (Let us say at the max 10 at any given time. The sever side load is never going to grow.) Now, the application is to distribute some files to my client systems. I have an option to either host it on my desktop or a XEON sever, both contain a single network card. In either case(Desktop/Server),sever is going to sit in the same network. Even though clients are limited but files can be large (in GBs) and all clients can request at the same time.

Now, I have to make a decision on which device to use as a server. I am also wondering what all would be thing should I consider to improve the download performance.

Desktop runs Core I7, 4th gen. 2TB HDD, 128GB Flash drive, 8GB RAM Xeo server. (I will put the specifications)

Compute may not going be the main bottle neck. It is all going to be network IO.
My network bandwidth can't be improved as I am sitting in the same network.
I can choose server as compute threads can be more. I will also have more RAM which will guarantee files will reside in main memory. File IO will be faster compared to desktop and so is L1/L2 cache.
I feel network performance will be not improve between desktop/xeon as it is bottlenecked by the network card.
Please, let me know what other factors would make one choice far better than other.
(Both are running Ubuntu 14.04(Desktop running client edition and xeon running the server edition.))

Comment: What kind of data? Movies, Music, Other. You are correct, the CPU isn't going to be the bottleneck. What will be your bottleneck is two parts. Network speed and the speed of your drives. If you use a gigabit network (which I suggest) your cap is around 120MB/s, so make sure your drives can keep up. Files are unlikely to stay in ram for any useful amount of time. Ram is best used for copies to the server to help with drive speeds and only if the sending machine is faster than the receiving machine. I'll give a full answer once I know what kind of data your are using this for.

Comment: It is mostly going to be movies/jpeg/music/custom data format files etc.

Comment: Will it be streaming or will the requesting system be doing the processing. Like, will you be watching the video's with Media Player Classic (whatever Ubuntu uses, I use windows and mint-mate so I don't know about Ubuntu Desktop defaults), or will you be using something like KODI?

Comment: No, it will first download the content. Once the content is  completely downloaded then only we can access the content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Network Equipment - If you don't have it already, get a Gigabit switch with enough ports for your router and all the systems that will connect to it. Your systems should already have gigabit on them. If they don't throw down the $15 bucks and get a pair. They aren't unreasonably expensive.

File Server, use the XEON system, especially if its ram is ECC (Error Correcting Code). The i7 series can't use ECC and ECC is great for keeping your data alive (meaning no ram related silent corruption). You'll always be doing battle with silent corruption, why complicate matters?

Since you are using Ubuntu Server 14.04 you have to decide what roles you want it to play. I suggest using SSH to communicate with the server. If the server has IPMI (Intelligent Platform Management Interface, look it up if you don't know) then take the monitor off and run it headless. I do suggest putting an passphrase-protected SSH key on it so the server is more secure, read ->  https://askubuntu.com/questions/2271/how-to-harden-an-ssh-server

After you've harden the server, you should probably use samba for file communications. You could use NFS (Network File System) since you're using only Linux machines, though it's better to get used to Samba in case you want to use a mix network. This is what I use at the bottom of /etc/samba/smb.conf

```
[Storage]
   comment = Storage
   path = /media/Storage
   browseable = yes
   read only = no
   guest ok = yes
   create mask = 0755
   writeable = yes
```

One thing you need to do is decide on a partition format. A lot can and will go wrong. From your listed specs it looks like you have a single drive, which is the normal starting place. I suggest using EXT4 on it since it's native to Linux. Others recommend EXT3 and honestly, either will work just fine for your purposes. If you decide to use more than one drive and want to pool the space into a single mount point, you have a few options. BTRFS has Raid equivalent 0,1,5,6 with 5 and 6 being experimental. There is also the tried and true mdadm which is easy enough to setup and will give you software raid. You can also go the pragmatis route and use somthing like AUFS (Another Unified File System) or MHDDFS (Multi-Hard Drive Disk File System). I prefer MHDDFS since it's simple, easy to use, and you don't need to compile it into the kernel. There is also Mergerfs though I haven't used it all that much. If you do go the pragmatic route I suggest using Snapraid to keep parity for the drives. You need to scrub 10% oldest once a month to keep silent data corruption in it's place.

Since you only have one drive there isn't anything you can really do about drive speed outside of buying faster drives. A 4TB WD Green drive with WDIDLE set to infinite runs above Gigabit speeds on my network so I just pooled the drives and used snapraid to keep my data safe.

It might also be worth your time to get a DNS and setup an ownCloud or FTP. You can host your own email, but the setup is a pain. You should also put together an rsync backup because raid is not backup. The list goes on and on.

I hope I've shed a little light on the problem. As always, read a lot. Linux is a useful OS but it's documentation is all over the place. Always check the date on the article to avoid reading ten pages of defunct material.

Comment: Thank you. I forgot to mention, you should probably read about encryption. dm-crypt with LUKS with a decent password can save you down the road. Your data is your treasure. Make sure all a thief gets is the hardware. If possible put your server in a secured room. If you really want to go the extra mile, create a destruction login. Far too often people think about security in hindsight; after the theft. Don't be one of those people. That goes for windows too. Use bitlocker/truecrypt bootloader on any drive that contains personal data. Some SSD's have AES encryption built into them.